# Java Script - Adding null value to array, if the element is not present at particular index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array length is 7

Original array

```
var arr = [2, 4, 6];
```

Needed array

```
arr = [null,null,2,null,4,null,6];
```

- 0 is not present in array so need to replace with null,
- 1 is not available replace with null and
- 2 is available so put 2 in new array so on..

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Because it appears that your data is a poor structure for whatever problem you have.  If you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, we can perhaps help you find a better type of data structure rather than converting one inefficient data structure to another inefficient one.

Comment: Iam using this in selecting week days array for sun -0 , mon-1, tue-2 like this. user can select one or more days in a week. iam pushing select days index in to array. need to push null value if days are not selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write a permanence case for all answers soon.

```
function createArrayFromArray(array, length) {

var new_array = new Array(length);

   for (var i = 0; i < new_array.length; i++) {
      new_array[i] = null;
   }

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      new_array[array[i]] = array[i];
   }

   return new_array;
}

console.log(createArrayFromArray(arr, 7)); //[null, null, 2, null, 4, null, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `splice()` method on the array

```
var arr=[2,4,6];
var l = arr[arr.length-1];
for(var i=0; i<=l; i++){
    if(arr[i] !== i){
        arr.splice(i, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Output : `[null, null, 2, null, 4, null, 6]`

This modifies the original array.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the max value in the array and then iterate from 0 to that max, checking each value to see if it was present in the source or not:

```
var arr = [2, 4, 6];

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
        result[i] = i;
    } else {
        result[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/c7p8mkqy/

---

As I asked in my comments, I'd like to know what problem you're actually trying to solve because it seems like both the original and the newly created data structures are inefficient structures that could probably use different form of data and work more efficiently.  But, we can only help you make a wiser choice if you explain the actual problem, rather just your attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have the only input `arr` which you want to fill null inside. Try this:

```
var arr = [2, 4, 6];

var output = [];
while (arr.length>0){
    var first = arr.splice(0,1);
    while (output.length<first[0])
        output.push(null);
    output.push(first[0]);
}

// output should be [null,null,2,null,4,null,6];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
var arr = [2, 4, 6];
var new_arr = [];
var i = 0;

while(i < 7){
 var pos = arr.indexOf(i++);
 new_arr.push(pos !== -1 ? arr[pos] : null)
}

 document.write(JSON.stringify(new_arr, null, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [2, 4, 6];
var result = new Array(7);
arr.forEach(function(a) { result[a] = a;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splice():

```js
var arr = [2, 4, 6];
var i = 0,
  l = arr[arr.length - 1];
while (i < l) {
  if(i !== arr[i])
    arr.splice(i, 0, null);
  i++;
}
console.log(arr); //[ null, null, 2, null, 4, null, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting quiz:

```
var arr = [2, 4, 6]
var n = 0

while(arr.length > n) {
  if(arr[n] !== n) {
    arr = arr.slice(0,n).concat(null, arr.slice(n))
  }
  n++
}

console.log(arr) // [null, null, 2, null, 4, null, 6]
```

This approach applies to array consists of random number of sorted integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [2, 4, 6];
var narr = (new Array(arr.sort()[arr.length-1]))
arr.map(function(v){
    narr[v] = v;
}); 
for (var i = 0; i<narr.length; i++) narr[i]||(narr[i]=null);
console.log(narr);
```